# PHP script not creating file

Tags: php, nginx

I have the PHP script below, which is intended to create a file from the payload of a POST request to NGINX.  The script echos the POST request contents back to the requester, but I find no new file in `/www/www/html/files`, which is where data should be saved.

Here is the POST request:

```
http://142.93.124.54/save.php
```

The body of the request is `data` (the key) and `This is a test!` (the value).  The reply to the request is

```
This is a test! | /var/www/html | /var/www/html/files/ | 
   /var/www/html/files/5b70334ddcecb19896.txt
```

I did `chmod 777 files` to see if permissions were part of the problem, but that did not change anything.

```
<?php
//FILE: save.php
$post_data = $_POST['data'];
echo($post_data);
echo(' | ');
echo(__DIR__);
echo(' | ');
if (!empty($post_data)) {
    $dir = '/var/www/html/files/';
    echo($dir);
    echo(' | ');
    $file = uniqid().getmypid();
    $filename = $dir.$file.'.txt';
    $handle = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $post_data);
    fclose($handle);
    echo $filename ;
}
?>
```

NOTE: if you are testing this, you need to do a POST request, not GET.

NOTE 2: I changed the directory to `/var/ww/html/file/` and confirmed that this should be correct by echoing `__DIR__`.  I also added a few other echo statements, e.g., one for the final filepath to which the data is written.  Alas, I find nothing in `var/www/html/files/`.

Comment: `/files` is not in `/var/www/html` its in `/`, use `./files` or `__DIR__.'/files'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at  `$dir = '/files';`.

You are pointing to your root directory. Change it to

`$dir = './files';`

Comment: OK!! Working now!